# Is there a way to make a custom qualifier in c++ to move data types to flash?

Tags: c++, avr

I am currently writing some code in c++ for a syntax similar to Arduino with some more features. Currently, I am working on making a way to call a program to the processor from an external flash. due to memory concerns. I have a couple of ideas for that and since I am using a custom bootloader, I can make it run code from the flash. However, the other problem I want to deal with is moving a data type to the external flash using a qualifier, similar to the `EXTMEM` qualifier in the teensy 4.0 code. How would I possibly do this?

I tried surfing the web for a solid 30 minutes to find an answer but I have not found anything satisfactory to me.

Edit: to clarify, I am mostly doing this for educational purposes. I am trying to make a microcontroller completely from scratch, with no dependencies other than the standard libraries (iostream, inttypes, etc.). I realized to do this I need to start at the bottom of this and use my instruction set to create this. I know this is an odd project, but I mostly choose these projects because of their oddness. To answer another question, I plan to use my bootloader to read from the external flash, copy the contents into the internal flash, and then excecute the program.

Comment: C++ doesn't provide the syntax for defining custom qualifiers *per se*. However, you maybe could use a class template 'wrapper' - say `template<typename T> class MyExtType` with a `T` data member and the necessary member functions to handle memory access.

Comment: "a syntax similar to Arduino": the Arduino toolchain should provide [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/) to "Store data in flash (program) memory instead of SRAM". Is it not available with your toolchain ? Or did it not suit your needs ?

Comment: Keep data in external flash has nothing to do with C++ language. There also seems to be some misunderstanding of how MCU work as compare to CPU (in your PC), for MCU, code are executed in flash memory, only dynamic data or variables get load into RAM (stack or heap). If you have an AVR chip, you are likely using avr-libc (even Arduino is based on it), to avoid data to be loaded into RAM (such as string literal or constants), [avr/pgmspace.h](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#ga75acaba9e781937468d0911423bc0c) provides the means to do that.

Comment: There are plenty of powerful 32-bit Arduino boards with lots of memory, you should probably just get one of them.  As far as I know, AVRs cannot run code from an external flash, the code must reside in the AVR.

Comment: To answer David: cost is a constraint in this build, and the ATmega328p is just an MCU that I know quite well, as that is the main MCU that I use for application.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question highly depends on the compiler you are using.

- There is no keyword in C standard.
- IAR Embedded Workbench has support for non-standard `__flash`, `__tinyflash`, `__farflash` and `__hughflash` keyword.
- *avr-libc* (often used with gcc) has `<avr/pgmspace.h>` header. The header includes a couple of functions and macros to access flash memory.
- gcc has `progmem` attribute for AVR. But you still need special functions to access FLASH, like in `<avr/pgmspace.h>`.
- In general, compilers that are designed for *Von Neumann architecture* (like gcc) usually use different segments for FLASH, EEPROM and SRAM. (But you still need special functions to access FLASH, like in `<arv/pgmspace.h>`.)
  e.g. One could make something like `const int someVar __attribute__((section(".text"))) = 123;`
  or `const int someVar __attribute__((section(".progmem"))) = 123;` - depending on your linker and its configuration...